# What is the php equivalent of @row:=@row+1

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `MySQL` statement that works successfully within the `SQL` database playground. It queries and returns **every 10th row** in my location_values table irrespective of any gaps in the ID's.

It looks like this:

> MySQL

```
set @row:=-1;

SELECT location_values.*
FROM
    location_values
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM
            (
                SELECT @row:=@row+1 AS rownum, id 
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT id FROM location_values ORDER BY id
                    ) AS sorted
            ) as ranked
        WHERE rownum % 10 = 0
    ) AS subset
        ON subset.id = location_values.id
```

[working db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dMDkLzgg64vLiLgXNZhFNT/1?fbclid=IwAR0c1lV8GoqRE3mI2fpdxHI2VBKq2-mUmJOdthGY6ZJ0gWSrmoF5h0X40B4)

Problem: I would like to convert this statement above and run it in a `PHP` query instead but I am having problems doing so.

As it currently stands my custom `PHP` function continues to print the entire table as opposed to every 10th row as per the MySQL statement. I suspect due to not interpreting `set @row:=-1;` and `@row:=@row+1` within `PHP`.

> My PHP function

```
function get_incidents() {

$row = -1;

$query = query("

SELECT location_values.*
FROM
    location_values
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM
            (
                SELECT $row + 1 AS rownum, id 
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT id FROM location_values ORDER BY id
                    ) AS sorted
            ) as ranked
        WHERE rownum % 10 = 0
    ) AS subset
        ON subset.id = location_values.id");


confirm($query); //passes in the global $connection;



while ($row = fetch_array($query)) {


$incidents = <<<DELIMETER



<tr>

    <td>{$row['id']}</td>
    <td>{$row['name']}</td>
    <td>{$row['lat']}</td>
    <td>{$row['lng']}</td>


</tr>



DELIMETER;

echo $incidents;


} // end of while loop    





} // end of function
```

I am newish to PHP and would be grateful for any steering as to how best refactor my PHP function to achieve my goal of returning every 10th row irrespective of gaps in the ID's.

Comment: Make your query a stored procedure and just call it with PHP.

Comment: You can not willy-nilly switch out SQL variables for PHP variables, and expect that to do the same thing … `@row:=@row+1` in the SQL gets executed for each record your subquery returns - `$row + 1` in the PHP code gets executed exactly _one_ time, before the query is passed to the database as _static_ text. These are two massively different things.

Comment: Good question. Is there a solution

Comment: @04FS thank you for the advice

Comment: Two options: Either select all records from the database, and then let PHP output only every 10th one of them (probably a bad idea, in terms of performance - 9 out of 10 records sent from the database to PHP would be effectively meaningless, but they still have to be transferred between the two) - or make PHP submit your query to the database as it was - meaning, leave the SQL variables in, instead of trying to switch them out for PHP variables.

Comment: You have two separate statements here, `set @row:=-1;`, followed by the `SELECT` query - you need to send both to the database. MySQLi can send multiple statements as one (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) - if that is not an option, then you will have to make two queries.

Comment: (Or, as @JayBlanchard said, make the whole thing into a prepared statement. But that probably increases the complexity a bit beyond a beginner’s level.)

Comment: Yes............

Comment: @04FS I have to point out that sending multiple statements via PHP is a terrible idea. Please use prepared statements.

Comment: @Dharman a) why? (especially in this instance), and b) you probably meant stored procedure, not prepared statement …? (Using a prepared statement changes nothing about the fact that there’s _two_ queries to be executed here.)

Comment: Why is sending multiple statements to MySQL a bad idea @Dharman?

Comment: @04FS It is a bad idea in general, not in this particular case. There's always a better way. Executing multiple statements using mysqli is very cumbersome and does not allow for parameterized queries. Granted in this case OP doesn't have parameters, but in general it is not recommended.

Comment: Could the objective be achieved using some sort of loop. Good thread and question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## MySQL >8.0

You can achieve the same task using a window function. If I am not mistaken the correct way to do it would be as follows:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT *, Row_number() OVER() AS rn FROM location_values) t 
WHERE t.rn % 10 = 1
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tb2nLZ6dkDPaQxkc6My9Yg/2

## MySQL <8.0

You can emulate the window function using session property, but this is not always reliable.

Method 1 (can only be executed once; don't recommend):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
    (SELECT *, @position:=((SELECT ifnull(@position, 0)) + 1) AS rn FROM location_values) t
WHERE t.rn % 10 = 1
```

Method 2:

```
SELECT location_values.*
FROM location_values,
    (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS temp
WHERE (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) % 10 = 1
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tb2nLZ6dkDPaQxkc6My9Yg/3

Comment: Appreciate this, I will give this a run in the php query and revert shortly

Comment: that works great in the SQL playground, but I am getting syntax error when I try and nest in PHP query, Is there any chance you could refactor into my PHP query. really appreciate your steering

Comment: here is an image containing RDBMS info https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1uwpmo5rwxtyzw/information.png?dl=0

Comment: I added the solution for older MySQL versions. Try the second method

Comment: Dharman may I take the opportunity to sincerely thank you. That code works lovely. Just ran it now. Its very lean syntax wise

Comment: Concur that is a elegant solution.

Comment: Interesting to see @row_number:=@row_number still being used. Superb code